# How do I get psionic death achievement in StarCraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

[image]

I'm trying to get this on unranked matches, hoping that unranked matches are under melee combat category. Do I have to kill 20 units in *one, single storm*, or do I have to have 20 or more kills in just one templar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get 20 kills with **one templar**,it can easily be tracked since your units have kills tracker in the lower middle under their name.

[There were some complaints about bugged kills tracking for this achievement.](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/540955204)

[Also you should be able to do this achievement by killing your own units in a game versus AI.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YefwUN-0KtU)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of well executed storm drops on a mineral line should put you pretty close to this achievement.